# Why don't each of T and B cells make two different TCRs/antibodies, except for the class switch?

Tags: immunology, antibody

I have not been able to find any literature that clearly states this, but if I understand correctly, T and B cells are diploid.

If so, there are two sets of genomes, and if both are TCR/VDJ reconstituted, it would seem that one cell would have two different TCR/antibodies. In other words, there will be a TCR/antibody produced by TCR/VDJ rearrangement of a patternal chromosome and a TCR/antibody produced by TCR/VDJ rearrangement of a maternal chromosome.
Why doesn't that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for this question  and obtained the answer, which I will expand on.

There is a mechanism called 'allele exclusion' (allelic exclusion),
which means that when one of a pair of immunoglobulin/TCR genes is successfully reconstituted and
becomes a functional gene, the other one ceases to function.
Eventually, only one or the other is expressed.

For more information, search for "allele exclusion" or "allelic exclusion".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allelic_exclusion
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12707333/